# How to explicitly specify value of AutoInc column in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

By default, Slick ignores values in columns with `O.AutoInc` flag and lets database to fill that value during insert operation.

But sometimes i need to insert some specific value for auto incrementing column and Slick still ignores it. Is there any way to do that?

I know, i can make second table definition, without `O.AutoInc` flag, but i'm looking for more elegant way to do it.

Update:
Here is my case class and table definition:

```
case class Transaction (id: Long, timestamp: LocalDateTime, comment: Option[String])
class Transactions(tag: Tag) extends Table[Transaction](tag, "tx") {
  implicit val localDTtoDate = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp] (
    l => Timestamp.valueOf(l),
    d => d.toLocalDateTime
  )

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def timestamp = column[LocalDateTime]("ts")
  def comment = column[Option[String]]("comment")
  def * = (id, timestamp, comment) <> ((Transaction.apply _).tupled, Transaction.unapply)
}
```

Comment: You can do this if your `*`-projection uses the ID column. Can you copy-paste your table definition?

Comment: @jkinkead Sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you mark your `id` field as `Option`al, you should be able to insert with a slight adjustment to your `*` projection:

```scala
case class Transaction (id: Option[Long], timestamp: LocalDateTime,
  comment: Option[String])
class Transactions(tag: Tag) extends Table[Transaction](tag, "tx") {
  // Use the ? method on your id column to map it to an option.
  def * = (id.?, timestamp, comment) <> (
    (Transaction.apply _).tupled, Transaction.unapply)
}
```

With this, rows that you insert with `id=None` will generate a new `id`, while rows with `id=Some(value)` will set `id=value`. To read back the inserted id, use `returning ... into`:

```
// `tx` is a Transaction instance, `transactions` is a
// TableQuery[Transactions] instance.
(transactions.returning(transactions.map(_.id)).into { (_, id) =>
  tx.copy(id = id)
}) += tx
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with id: Option[Long] value is still autogenerated in both cases, with Some(value) and with None

Comment: How are you inserting rows? What database are you using? This should work with Slick 3.{0,1} and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Insertion code is part of for comprehension, relevant part is: transactions returning transactions.map(_.id) += tx database is PostgreSQL

Comment: Ah. You problem is actually within that code. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @akashihi you need to do .forceInsert instead of `+=` http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#inserting

Comment: @Falmarri with forceInsert i will not be able to insert values _without_ id

Comment: @jkinkead Nope, even with modified insertion code id is still ignored

Comment: I'm baffled. I've used this exact code with Slick 3.0 & 3.1, on Postgres 9.5. Are you using an older version of Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while struggling with a very similar issue.
Sadly, we could not make the suggested solution work either.

We decided to let the `O.AutoInc` go, but kept the sequence and the default value of the column to be the `nextval` of that sequence

```
  Column  |  Type  |                 Modifiers
----------+--------+----------------------------------------------
 id       | bigint | not null default nextval('id_seq'::regclass)
```

Then we just omitted the id during insertion when it needed to be generated automatically.

Link to the relevant part of the documentation:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#inserting

In this exact case it would look something like this:

```
if (you have an explicit id) transactions += tx
else transactions.map(t => (t.timestamp, t.comment)) += (tx.timestamp, tx.comment)
```